# how do i extract my data from json file so i can put it inner html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

i am trying to extract my data from JSON file i even used .map() to map out the data but it ends up showing error that result.map() is not a defined function. how do i show extract data

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JSON Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myData"></div>
        <!-- Here a loader is created which 
             loads till response comes -->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border" 
                 role="status" id="loading">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Registered Employees</h1>
        <!-- table for showing data -->
        <table id="employees"></table>
    </body>
    <script src="api1-2.js"></script>>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `response.json()` instead of `response.text()`.

`response.json()` and `response.text()` both return a Promise, but `response.json()` resolves that Promise to a JavaScript object while `response.text()` resolves that Promise to a String.

References:

- [Response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json)
- [Response.tex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `response.txt()` with `response.json()` to parse api response to json object. with response.text() your result is in string, so it does not have map method and hence the `undefined` error.

```
fetch("https://v1.nocodeapi.com/OPENSOURCE12/instagram/gflSSOQjdOHsVnhT", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json()) //  modified
    .then(result => {console.log(result)})
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: it still say .map is not a function

Comment: arrays have .map funciton. check if what you're trying to iterate using .map func is an array or not. if you are trying result.map and result is in `{ }` format, you will get same error

Comment: so the array in jason file is named as data so i tried using result.data.map() , i tried removing the object but i am getting no where here

Comment: just to be clear, result.data is  array `[ ]` or  object `{ }`?

Comment: result is an object, {}

Comment: object does not have map function